# JSON Fetch into iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing

http://xtremeinspection.com/new2you4kids/app/android/get_category_brand.php

Above is the URL of JSON.

I want to show data on xcode whose "PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" = "0".

I have used following coding :

```
-(void) loadJSON
{
loadJSONData = [NSURL URLWithString:mainURL];

    NSLog(@"Fetch JSON URL : %@",loadJSONData);

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        loadJSONData];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError* error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization
            JSONObjectWithData:responseData
            options:kNilOptions
            error:&error];
    adultJSON = [json objectForKey:@"category"];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", adultJSON);

    NSDictionary *typeData = [json objectForKey:@"category"];
    categTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (NSDictionary *types in typeData)
    {
        if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[adultJSON valueForKey:@"PARENT_CATEGORY_ID"]] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            [categTypeArray addObject:[types valueForKey:@"PARENT_CATEGORY_ID"]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", adultJSON);
    NSLog(@"Category Data: %@", categTypeArray);
}
```

But categTypeArray returns null.

Which method i should used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is with the following code:

```
if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[adultJSON valueForKey:@"PARENT_CATEGORY_ID"]] isEqualToString:@"0"])
```

You wrote `adultJSON` instead of `types`.

Change that code to:

```
if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[types valueForKey:@"PARENT_CATEGORY_ID"]] isEqualToString:@"0"])
```

Comment: You should mention that the call to `stringWithFormat:` is highly superfluous.

Comment: @Midhun MP  The code you suggested will throw an exception and crash the app if `[types valueForKey:@"PARENT_CATEGORY_ID"]` does not return an NSString object.  For example, if it returns an NSDictionary, you will crash because NSDictionary does not respond to the selector isEqualToString.

Comment: @MidhunMP Typecasting wouldn't help in that case.

Comment: Casting an object to something else does not convert it.  It does nothing when the code is compiled.  It's just to help the debugger help you, for example to autocomplete methods only available on strings, or to warn you if you do something wrong.  It doesn't change the type of object in any way.

Comment: @MidhunMP Possible. However, if that `stringWithFormat:` indeed helps, then OP has a serious misunderstanding about how he should use collection objects.

Comment: You may want to look at the `-isKindOfClass:`, `-isMemberOfClass:` and `-isSubclassOfClass:` methods.